# Is it essential for two meshing gears to have even number of teeth?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms, machine-design, machine-elements

Should the teeth of meshing gears be even rather than odd numbers? If not, which is better?

Comment: Won’t larger gears have more teeth - the circumference changes so the number of teeth has to change…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommendation is quite the opposite.

The teeth of meshing gears are, where possible, chosen to be odd or, better again, primes so that a bad tooth doesn't keep hitting the same point on the opposing gear and gear wear will be even. For example, 23 tooth gear driven by a 19 tooth gear will only come back into phase after 19 × 23 = revolutions.

You need to confirm this, but as far as I know the tooth repeat frequency is given by
$\frac {LCM}{T_1 \times T_2}$  where $ LCM $ is the least common multiple of the number of teeth on the two gears and $ T_1 $ and $ T_2 $ are the number of teeth on each gear.